# Как пишут игры с подключением к серверу?

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Допустим, нужно реализовать игру - мультиплеер по сети. Допустим, крестики-нолики. Будет поиск соперника и игра с ним. Как продумать логику сервера и клиента? Ведь первый игрок должен как-то получить информацию о том, что ход второго игрока выполнен. Объясните, пожалуйста, как можно подробнее. Хочу использовать `Retrofit` в проекте, это правильный выбор?

Comment: Для многопользовательских игр обычно используют соединение по TCP или UDP, а не дергают серевер через REST/HTTP, именно для того, чтобы сервер мог послать пакет клиенту.

Comment: Меня пугает текущая тенденция пихать Retrofit во все, что хоть сколько-нибудь связано с интернетом. Retrofit -- это REST-клиент, ни больше ни меньше.

Comment: А разве планируемая игра  это не REST-клиент?

Comment: Вы же хотите полноценное взаимодейтсвие пользователей в обе стороны. REST для данной задачи не лучшее решение. Подумайте о websockets или о своем протоколе поверх TCP.

Comment: А есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека? Просто надоело уже много кода слишком..

Comment: Можете попробовать [kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet). Там готовый стек прикладного уровня, а пакеты - обычные POJO.